# C# SQLite transaction - Is this usage valid?

Tags: c#, sqlite, transactions

I've started dabbling in C# and am writing a section of code to handle inserting two tables into my SQLite database, and only inserting rows for "Platforms" if the platform in question doesn't already exist.

The code works as intended, but I am seeking validation on whether I'm handling transactions correctly.

Would also appreciate any pointers on anything that seems funky or could be improved upon.

Thank you

```cs
private static string databaseFilePath = @"Data\";
private static string databaseFileName = "myDB.db";
private static string databaseFullPath = String.Concat(databaseFilePath, databaseFileName);
private static string platformTableName = "Platforms";
private static string gameTableName = "Games";

// Create our tables
private async void CreateTables(SQLiteConnection connection, SQLiteTransaction transaction)
{
    // SQLite query string to create the Platform table
    string createPlatformTableQuery = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [" + platformTableName + @"] (
        [Id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        [Name] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [ShortCode] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [Description] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [ReleaseDate] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [Images] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [Video] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [RomPaths] TEXT NOT NULL
    )";

    // SQLite query string to create the Games table
    string createGamesTableQuery = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [" + gameTableName + @"] (
        [Id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        [Platform] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [Name] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [Crc] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [Screenshots] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [FanArt] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [BoxArt] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [CartArt] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [DiscArt] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [Music] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [Video] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [Players] INTEGER NOT NULL,
        [Description] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [ReleaseDate] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [Publisher] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [Developer] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [Rating] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [PlayCount] INTEGER NOT NULL,
        [PlayTime] REAL NOT NULL,
        [FilePath] TEXT NOT NULL
    )";

    // Create an SQLite command
    using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
    {
        try
        {
            // Set the command to create our platform table
            command.CommandText = createPlatformTableQuery;
            // Execute the query
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

            // Set the command to create our games table
            command.CommandText = createGamesTableQuery;
            // Execute the query
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
        // We encountered an exception
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            // Rollback the transaction
            transaction.Rollback();
            // Throw the exception
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

// Insert Platforms (defined in PlatformList.cs) into the platforms table
private async void InsertPlatforms(SQLiteConnection connection, SQLiteTransaction transaction, PlatformList platformList)
{
    // Is this a fresh population of the Platforms table data?
    bool freshPopulation = false;

    // Create an SQLite command
    using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
    {
        try
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) from " + platformTableName;
            var count = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
            freshPopulation = Convert.ToInt16(count) <= 0;
        }
        // We encountered an exception
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            // Rollback the transaction
            transaction.Rollback();
            // Throw the exception
            throw e;
        }
    }

    // Loop through the platform list
    foreach (var item in platformList.list)
    {
        // Populate an array from all items in each platformList entry
        string[] values = new string[]
        {
            item.name, item.shortCode, item.description, item.releaseDate, item.images, item.video
        };
        // Comma quote the values
        string commaQuotedValues = "'" + String.Join("','", values) + "'";
        string commandText = String.Concat("INSERT INTO ", platformTableName, " (Name, ShortCode, Description, ReleaseDate, Images, Video) Values (", commaQuotedValues, ")");

        // Create an SQLite command
        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
        {
            try
            {
                // If this is the first time we are inserting data into the platforms table
                if (freshPopulation)
                {
                    // Set the command text
                    command.CommandText = commandText;
                    // Execute the query
                    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
                // There is already data in the platforms table.. Let's ensure that it's up to date
                else
                {
                    // Set the command to select an existing row from the platforms table (if it exists)
                    command.CommandText = @"SELECT ShortCode FROM " + platformTableName + " WHERE ShortCode='" + item.shortCode + "'";

                    // Start the data reader
                    using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        // If this row isn't already inserted into the database
                        if (!reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            // Insert any rows not already inserted into the platforms table
                            using (SQLiteCommand insertCommand = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    // Set the command text
                                    insertCommand.CommandText = commandText;
                                    // Execute the query
                                    await insertCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                                }
                                // We encountered an exception
                                catch (SQLiteException e)
                                {
                                    // Rollback the transaction
                                    transaction.Rollback();
                                    // Throw the exception
                                    throw e;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // We encountered an exception
            catch (SQLiteException e)
            {
                // Rollback the transaction
                transaction.Rollback();
                // Throw the exception
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Init
public async void Init()
{
    // Create an instance of the platform list
    PlatformList platformList = new PlatformList();

    // If the database doesn't exist
    if (!File.Exists(databaseFullPath))
    {
        // Create the database
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(databaseFullPath);
    }

    // Create an SQLite connection to the database
    using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"data source=" + databaseFullPath))
    {
        // Open the connection to the database
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        // Start a transaction
        using (SQLiteTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            // Create the required tables
            CreateTables(connection, transaction);

            // Insert platforms into the Platforms table
            InsertPlatforms(connection, transaction, platformList);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transaction is not complete if the code is aborted due to any exception; you should not restrict the rollback to `SQLiteException`s.

To re-throw the current exception, you should use `throw;` without specifying the exception object; otherwise, the exception information (stack trace etc.) would be reset.

In SQLite, a connection can have only a single transaction, so you do not need to tell the command objects which transaction to use (this might be different for other databases).

To roll back the transaction, you need only a single `try`/`catch`, which should be done where you create the transaction (remove all other `catch`es):

```
using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        CreateTables(connection);
        InsertPlatforms(connection, platformList);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, that makes complete sense. Thank you so much for the detailed answer